# ViewDidAppear doesn't work when i call it in iOS 4.3?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, ipad, objective-c-2.0, viewdidappear

I have a UITabBarController that include four UIViewController and when i want call viewDidAppear it doesn't work. I don't why this happens just for iOS 4.3?

```
//
UINavigationController *nav3 = [[UINavigationController alloc] init];
SearchViewController *searchViewController = [[SearchViewController alloc] init];
searchViewController.context = context;

[nav3 pushViewController:searchViewController animated:NO];
[arrayViewController addObject:nav3];

[nav3 release]; [searchViewController release];

//
UINavigationController *nav4 = [[UINavigationController alloc] init];
FavorisViewController *favorisViewController = [[FavorisViewController alloc] init];
favorisViewController.context = context;

[nav4 pushViewController:favorisViewController animated:NO];
[arrayViewController addObject:nav4];

[nav4 release]; [favorisViewController release];
```

My Favorite UIViewController:

```
     #pragma mark - View lifecycle

     - (void)viewDidLoad
      {
         [super viewDidLoad];

          NSError *error;
          NSFetchRequest *fetch = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
          fetch.entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Businesses" inManagedObjectContext:context];
          fetchObject = [context executeFetchRequest:fetch error:&error];

         [fetch release];

        }

      - (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
       {
          NSLog(@"test");
       }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using the `UINavigationController` method `initWithRootViewController:` instead. For example,

```
FavorisViewController *favorisViewController = [[FavorisViewController alloc] init];
favorisViewController.context = context;
UINavigationController *nav4 = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:favorisViewController];
[favorisViewController release];
```

Note as well that just because the view is pushed onto the stack, doesn't mean it's visible. Until you select the tab with that view, `viewDidAppear:` should not be called.